# How to block a content type from the RSS feed

Tags: 7, feeds

I simply want to remove one of my content types from being displayed in the feed, I can't find a solution anywhere - I would have thought there would be an option under Content Types which says "Don't put in feed" lol

Answer (score 4):

> I would have thought there would be an option under Content Types which says "Don't put in feed"

Yes, it's as simple as that. Simply uncheck the *"Promoted to front page"* from the content type settings and that content type's nodes won't be included in the RSS feed. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can You can use the [Views module](http://drupal.org/project/views) to generate an RSS feed, rather than relying on the default feed that Drupal provides. [This Tribute Media post](http://www.tributemedia.com/education/tutorials/custom_rss_feed_drupal) will step you through the basics.

Comment: I had done precisely that, however the <link> tag in the head remains the default `rss.xml`, so sites picking up my feed from the base URL will still see all of my content types.

Answer (score 2):

It seem's that in Drupal 7 we cannot hide some content types from the RSS feed.

What I suggest you to do is to use the [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module and then:

- Create a new view of type "Feed".
- In "Feed settings", set the "Path" to `/rss.xml` so it will overwrite the main feed.
- In `Filter criteria` add a filter criterion to "Content: Type" and set it to the content types that you want.